# PyQt5 - Need QCompleter or equivalent in non-editable QComboBox

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

Using PyQt5 I have a requirement for a drop-down read-only list of items, from which the user can select one.

As these items look quite similar, and their text mostly includes increasing integers, e.g. C000345, C000367, etc and there are several dozen of them, it would be easier for the operator if instead of going cross-eyed scanning the whole list they could type say "36" to see only the items containing the string "36", or arrive at the position of the first such item.

However, there is NO necessity for the operator to be able to edit any of the items or change the list. As I said, it is just a simple selection drop down.

But by an apparently lunatic aspect of Qt5 design these two requirements conflict: To be able to define a QCompleter, or even use the QComboBox's default QCompleter, the drop-down must be defined as Editable. Defining it as non-editable immediately nukes any associated QCompleter.

So in summary, I wondered if there is any simple way to implement this, i.e. if a QComboBox (or whatever similar widget it takes) comprises lines say "A", "B", "C", then I want the operator to be able to select "C" by simply typing "C". But I don't want them to be able to change any of these lines or add new ones. It shouldn't be rocket science, but apparently with PyQt5 and Qt5 it is!

Comment: Would it be appropriate to have a QLineEdit that only allows filtering the data of the QComboBox?

Comment: Many thanks for your prompt repy eyllansec. I asked the same question, hopefully in a simpler form, at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54324000/how-to-code-a-drop-down-selection-box-with-auto-completer-in-qt5-pyqt5 So I guess the above entry can be marked as a duplicate. I'm starting to think that maybe the term auto-complete is a misnomer in the present context, because my code is not seeking to "complete" anything only to locate strings in the list.

Comment: please avoid asking the same question in several posts, it is advisable to edit your question indicating your progress, I have marked this question as a duplicate because the other question is better posed.

Comment: FYI Stack Overflow mods, this very useful question was closed as a duplicate of a question that has now been removed for some reason which is really quite annoying. For anyone else with a similar problem, this answer was helpful for setting up a QComboBox that can be searched/filtered without affecting the entries themselves (which is not obvious thanks to the default behavior of automatically appending whatever the user types to the combo box entries): https://stackoverflow.com/a/61510686/929315