# Using PyQt5, How do I make a QComboBox searchable?

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I am using PyQt5 to make a GUI. On it, I have a QComboBox that has a dropdown list that has over 400 items. I was wondering if there is any way in which I can type into the QComboBox to search for a matching case?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use a `QCompleter` for this. For an editable `QComboBox` a `QCompleter` is created automatically. This completer performs case insensitive inline completion but you can adjust that if needed, for example

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from itertools import product

app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

# wordlist for testing
wordlist = [''.join(combo) for combo in product('abc', repeat = 4)]

combo = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
combo.addItems(wordlist)

# completers only work for editable combo boxes. QComboBox.NoInsert prevents insertion of the search text
combo.setEditable(True)
combo.setInsertPolicy(QtWidgets.QComboBox.NoInsert)

# change completion mode of the default completer from InlineCompletion to PopupCompletion
combo.completer().setCompletionMode(QtWidgets.QCompleter.PopupCompletion)

combo.show()
app.exec()
```

Comment: Wow! That was so simple to add to my pre-existing combo box!